# Define a bijection

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory, examples-counterexamples

Okay so I know that I asked this already but I want to ask how much progress I have made. so the question is

Construct a bijection between $[1,2]$ and $[3,5)$

So I have:
\begin{equation}
f(x) = \left \{ \begin{array}{ll} 3 + 2^{1-n} & \textrm{ if } x = 1+2^{1-n} \textrm{ for }  n \in \mathbb{N} \\
              2x+1 & \textrm{ if }  x \neq 1+2^{1-n} \end{array} \right.
\end{equation}

Sorry about the formatting, but is this correct?

Edit: the linked post is mine. I'm just asking since I didn't get a really satisfactory answer if the solution I have is going towards the right direction.

Edit2: changing the equation to what improvements I'm getting, still any feedback is helpful. Thanks!

Comment: So I think maybe it should be \begin{equation}
f(x) = \left \{ \begin{array}{ll} 3 + 2^{1-n} & \textrm{ if } x = 3+2^{2-n} \textrm{ for }  n \in \mathbb{N} \\
              2n+1 & \textrm{ if }  x \neq  3+2^{2-n} \end{array} \right.
\end{equation}  because so I want the first n=1 to equal to 5 to replace it to the next term and the next term. am i on the right track?

Comment: Umm,  what's the $n$ in case 2 referring to?

Comment: @Alan n is all natural number

Comment: @RodrigoZepeda Zepeda, that questoin was submited by me actually, i"m just asking since I come a little farther and I want to know if I am on the right tracks.

Comment: actually whoops I think the second one equation should be 2x+1, my bad

Comment: \begin{equation}
f(x) = \left \{ \begin{array}{ll} 3 + 2^{-n} & \textrm{ if } x = 3+2^{1-n} \textrm{ for }  n \in \mathbb{N} \\
              2x+1 & \textrm{ if }  x \neq 3+2^{1-n} \end{array} \right.
\end{equation}

Comment: I am not sure I am understanding your notation. If $x \in [1,2]$ then all $x$ fall in the second case of $f(x)$. In particular $x = 2$ maps to $x = 5$ which is not included in the set.

Comment: @joshua23 In your previous question you had an answer by user254665. I fail to see what is wrong with that answer. Could you please elaborate more?

Comment: I think you are right, i"m think that now instead it should be  $x = 1+2^{1-n}$

Comment: @RodrigoZepeda changed it does it make sense now?

Comment: @joshua23 Check the case $x = 2$ it falls in the first case with $n = 1$ and $f(x) = 3$. On the other hand, $x = 1$ falls in the second case and $f(x) = 3$. This is not a bijection either.

Comment: @RodrigoZepeda if n=1 then f(x) =4, because $3+2^{1-1} = 3+2^0=4$

Comment: @joshua23 Right! Sorry about that...

Comment: @RodrigoZepeda It's okay, I think this equation work now right?

Comment: @joshua23 I think so...

Answer (score 0):

The function $f$ is **onto**:

**Case 1**

Let $y \in [3,5) $ be of the form: $3 + 2^{1-n}$ for some $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Then $x = 1 + 2^{1-n}$ is such that $f(x) = y$. In particular, if $n$ is such that $3 + 2^{1-n} \in [3,5)$ then $n \geq 0$. This in turn implies that $1 \leq 1 + 2^{1-n} \leq 2$.

**Case 2**

Let $y \in [3,5) $ not be of the form: $3 + 2^{1-n}$ for some $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Then $x = (y-1)/2 \in [1,2]$ is such that $f(x) = y$. In particular if $y \in [3,5) $ then $(y-1)/2 \in [1,2]$.

The function $f$ is **inyective**:

Let $a,b \in [1,2]$ be such that $f(a) = y = f(b)$

**Case 1**

If $y \neq 3 + 2^{1-n}$ then $f(a) = 2a + 1 = 2b + 1 = f(b)$. It follows that $a = b$.

**Case 2**
If $y =  3 + 2^{1-n}$ then $f(a) = 3 + 2^{1-n_a}$ and $f(b) =  3 + 2^{1-n_b}$ where $a = 1 + 2^{1-n_a}$ and $b = 1 + 2^{1-n_b}$ respectively. Then: 
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
3 + 2^{1-n_a} = 3 + 2^{1-n_a} & \Leftrightarrow 2^{1-n_a} = 2^{1-n_a} \\ & \Leftrightarrow  log_2\left(2^{1-n_a}\right) = log_2\left(2^{1-n_b}\right) \\ & \Leftrightarrow n_a = n_b \\ & \Leftrightarrow a = b. 
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}